# Inverse of a $2\times2$ matrix with noncommuting entries

Tags: matrices, noncommutative-algebra, quaternions

I want to invert a $2 \times 2$ matrix with quaternionic entries. Since non-commutativity, the determinant is not well defined and I've seen in http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Quaternionic_matrix that, to test the invertibility, I can use the determinat of the $4 \times 4$ complex matrix that correspond to the rapresentation of each quaternion by a $2 \times 2$ complex matrix. But that page of Wikipedia does not give any rule to write the inverse matrix. There is some rule to do so?

Here is what I found.

If an inverse exists it's both left and right, since $M(2,\mathbb{H})$ is a group.  So I try  a matrix such that:
$$
  \left[ 
\begin{array}{ccccc}
a&b\\
c&d\\
\end{array}
\right]
 \left[ 
\begin{array}{ccccc}
x&y\\
z&t\\
\end{array}
\right] =
 \left[ 
\begin{array}{ccccc}
ax+bz&ay+bt\\
cx+dz&cy+dt\\
\end{array}
\right]
=
 \left[ 
\begin{array}{ccccc}
1&0\\
0&1\\
\end{array}
\right]
$$
equivalent to
$$
\begin{cases}
ax +bz=1\\
cx+dz=0\\
\end{cases}
\qquad \land \qquad
\begin{cases}
ay+bt=0\\
cy+dt=1
\end{cases}
$$
If one of a,b,c,d are $0$ the solution is simple. For $a,b,c,d \ne 0$, we find

$$
\begin{cases}
x=-c^{-1}dz\\
z=\left(b-ac^{-1}d\right)^{-1}
\end {cases}
\qquad
\begin{cases}
y=-a^{-1}bt\\
t=\left(d-ca^{-1}b\right)^{-1}
\end{cases}
$$
I fear that there is no simpler solution... or someone knows?

Comment: I'm not entirely positive but I would say, convert the 2x2 quaternionic matrix into a 4x4 complex matrix, invert the 4x4 and then convert it back to a 2x2 quaternionic matrix.

Comment: @Mastrel it's a long way.... I'm searching a shortcut.

Comment: Let $M_4$ be the complex $4\times 4$ matrix and $D = \det M_4$. Then the inverse of the $2\times 2$ matrix of quaternions will be a matrix of quaternions times $D$. The entries themselves are rather complicated.

Comment: @AleksVlasev. I added some calculations to the question. But I don't see the determinant $D$.

Comment: The suggestion to transplant the problem into $\Bbb M_4( C)$ is certainly pretty good considering that computers would be able to do the translation and inverse easily. An actual formula for the inverse looks really messy, not nearly as simple as a $2\times 2$ matrix over a field.

Comment: Actually your computation is pretty satisfactory, no?

Comment: Yes, it works. I was searching for something more simple that can be generalized to $n \times n$, but it seems that it does not exists.

Comment: @EmilioNovati Here you are assuming that $a$ and $c$ are nonzero. So this doesn't give a general nor a defined formula since you should also consider the case where $b$ and $d$ are nonzero, giving rise to at least two different inverses. Have you found any shortcut yet?

Answer (score 1):

Let $X=\begin{pmatrix}x&y\\z&w\end{pmatrix}$ be in $M_2(\mathbb H)$ then
$$X^{-1}=\frac{1}{n(x)n(w)+n(y)n(z)-\operatorname{tr}(\overline{y}x\overline{z}w)}\begin{pmatrix}n(w)\overline{x}-\overline{z}w\overline{y}&n(y)\overline{z}-\overline{x}y\overline{w}\\n(z)\overline{y}-\overline{w}z\overline{x}&n(x)\overline{w}-\overline{y}x\overline{z}\end{pmatrix}.$$
Note that $n(x)n(w)+n(y)n(z)-\operatorname{tr}(\overline{y}x\overline{z}w)$ is the reduced norm of $X$.