# Inverse of a 2x2 quaternion matrix: whence this formula?

Tags: linear-algebra, abstract-algebra, matrices, quaternions, noncommutative-algebra

From [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1044249/inverse-of-a-2-times2-matrix-with-noncommuting-entries), the inverse of a $2\times2$ quaternion matrix is given by

$$ \begin{bmatrix} 
 a & b \\
 c & d 
   \end{bmatrix}^{-1}
=\frac{1}{\mathrm{Nrd}} 
   \begin{bmatrix} 
 |d|^2\overline{a}-\overline{c}d\overline{b} &
   |b|^2\overline{c}-\overline{a}b\overline{d} \\
 |c|^2\overline{b}-\overline{d}c\overline{a} & |a|^2\overline{d}-\overline{b}a\overline{c}
   \end{bmatrix} \tag{1}$$

where the so-called "reduced norm" of the matrix is given by

$$ \mathrm{Nrd}\Big(\begin{bmatrix} a & b \\ c & d \end{bmatrix}\Big)=|a|^2|d|^2+|b|^2|d|^2-2\mathrm{Re}(\overline{b}a\overline{c}d). \tag{2}$$

This answer surprised me: I, proceeding like the OP, found two formulas involving noncommutative rational functions (so to speak) depending on whether the diagonal or antidiagonal entries were both nonzero. I was not expecting this.

But the user that posted this is long gone and gave no explanation. Via searching, I found the reduced norm $\mathrm{Nrd}(a)$ of an element $a\in A$ of a central simple algebra $A$ of dimension $n^2$ over a field $K$ is characterized by $\det(L_a)=(\mathrm{Nrd}\,a)^n$, where $L_a(x)=ax$ is considered a $K$-linear endomorphism of $A$ as a $K$-vector space. Or, equivalently, there is some field extension $L/K$ which is a "splitting field" for $A$ in the sense that $A\otimes L\cong M_n(L)$ and then $\mathrm{Nrd}$ is just $\det$ taken in $M_n(L)$ (but the result necessarily lands in $K$). The "reduced trace" $\mathrm{Trd}\,a$ can be defined similarly. User "johgi" used the notation $\mathrm{tr}$ for the reduced trace, and I figured out this is twice the real part.

**Q1**. Where does the formula $(2)$ for the reduced norm $\mathrm{Nrd}\,\big[\begin{smallmatrix}a&b\\c&d\end{smallmatrix}\big]$ come from?

Of course, a tedious calculation can verify the formula, but I expect cannot demystify its origin. I notice for reals it factors as $(ad-bc)^2$, so $(1)$ looks like a "rehomogenized" version of the adjugate formula for a matrix inverse.

**Q2**. Where does the formula $(1)$ for the $2\times2$ matrix inverse come from?

I can check that it is indeed an inverse, using $2\mathrm{Re}(x)=x+\overline{x}$ and $\mathrm{Re}(xy)=\mathrm{Re}(yx)=\mathrm{Re}(\bar{x}\bar{y})$ and $\mathrm{Re}(xyz)=\mathrm{Re}(zxy)=\mathrm{Re}(yzx)$. Multiplying the matrix with its inverse, it seems like the reduced norm has "pieces" which come together, so I wouldn't be surprised if the answers to Q1 and Q2 were intertwined.

I notice if we define $L_a(x)=ax$ and $R_a(x)=xa$ along with $X(p)=L_dR_a-L_cR_b$ and its adjoint $X^\ast(p)=L_{\overline{d}}R_{\overline{a}}-L_{\overline{c}}R_{\overline{b\,}}$ (viewing $\mathbb{H}$ as an inner product space), we have

$$ \begin{bmatrix} a & b \\ c & d \end{bmatrix}^{-1}
= \frac{1}{\mathrm{Nrd}}
\begin{bmatrix} \phantom{-}X^\ast(d) & -\overline{X(\overline{b})} \\
 -X^\ast(c) & \phantom{-}\overline{X(\overline{c})} \end{bmatrix}, $$

which looks a lot like an adjugate. Dunno what to make of that.

**Q3**. Does this generalize to other dimensions and algebras?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$
\def\mc#1{\left[\begin{array}{r|rrr}#1\end{array}\right]}
\def\m#1{\left[\begin{array}{r}#1\end{array}\right]}
\def\qif{\quad\iff\quad}
\def\M{{\cal M}}
$Transform each component quaternion into its $4\times 4$ matrix representation, e.g.
$$\eqalign{
a = \mc{a_1\\a_2\\a_3\\a_4}
 \qif
&A = \mc{
a_1 & -a_2 & -a_3 & -a_4 \\\hline
a_2 &  a_1 & -a_4 &  a_3 \\
a_3 &  a_4 &  a_1 & -a_2 \\
a_4 & -a_3 &  a_2 &  a_1 },
\quad
A^{-1} = \frac{A^T}{|a|^2} \\
}$$
Construct the equivalent block matrix and calculate its inverse
$$\eqalign{
&M = &\m{a&b\\c&d} &\qif \M = \mc{A&B\\\hline C&D} \\
&&\qquad M^{-1} &\qif \M^{-1} \\
}$$
via the [Schur complements](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Schur_complement) of $\M$.
This will recover the formula of interest.

For quaternionic matrices larger than $2\times 2$, the block matrix approach remains valid for **numerical** purposes, but the corresponding **symbolic** formulas quickly become intractable.

Comment: Ah, I see what you mean now. You're not actually computing the multiplications and inversions that I was thinking of really, at least not directly; you're symbolically replacing the expression $X^{-1}$ with the expression $X^T/|x|^2$ whenever $X$ is the matrix associated to a quaternion $x$, even when $X$ is itself an expression like $|d|^2A-BD^TC$. That makes a lot of sense.

Comment: That is correct.  And expressions like $|d|^2A-BD^TC$ come directly from the Schur Complement of the block matrix.